# Deleting first two letters from string field usimng Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm looking for a field calculator Python statement to delete only the first two letters of string entries.
For Ex:

```
!Name!.strip([0:2])
```

I know this syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You slice the string to be the third character through the end of the string (strings are zero indexed).

```
!Name![2:]
```